# Regex for incorrectly formatted pipe-separated csv file

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex to identify occurrences of unescaped double-quote characters in a pipe-delimited csv file. I.e. the file is pipe delimited and each field is surrounded by double-quotes, but some fields contain single double-quote characters that should be escaped with an extra double-quote to conform to RFC4180.
I.e.

> "Field1"|"Field 2 ""text in text"""|" is correct" 
>  "Field1"|"Field 2
>   "text in text""|" is incorrect"

because in the first line a single double-quote has been correctly escaped with another double-quote character.

I'm looking for a test to find the incorrectly escaped double-quotes

I can find double-quotes not preceded by a pipe with `[^|]\"`
and I can find double-quotes not followed by a pipe with `\"[^|]`
But that's where I'm stuck

Find double-quotes not preceded by pipe AND not followed by pipe AND not preceded or followed by a double-quote

Comment: I.e. 
"Field1"|"Field 2 ""text in text"""|"is correct"

Comment: "Field1"|"Field 2 "text in text""|"is incorrect"

Comment: I suggest that you use a CSV parser and don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Use [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) for parsing CSV files.

Comment: I AM using Apache Commons - I'm trying to find the specific errors in csv files being incorrectly generated by an upstream process which doesn't output files conforming to RFC4180 so the CSVFormat.RFC4180 parser fails...

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the work intended

[`(?<!^|\[|"\])"(?!\[|"\]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/8XPwOf/1)

Basically, it will look behind and search for anything but `^` (start of line), `|` or `"`.

It will do the same forward but instead of the beginning of the line, it will check for the end of line `$`

Comment: Thanks for that, nearly, but not quite

Comment: With the following example there should be only 2 matches, the 4th occurrence  and the 5th occurrence. No character should be matched if preceded by a pipe OR followed by a pipe as those look like valid field delimiters, but if the double-quote appears as a single character within a field then it is invalid
|"ghghjghj"|""bgjhhg"|" "ghjgjhg"|"hhkjhk""hkkjhj"|

Comment: I think this is more complex than I originally thought and I will have to consume this line by line checking until I have an inconsistency, i.e.   
1. consume line expecting to start with quote character  
2. consume text expecting to end with quote character followed by delimiter  
3. If encounter quote not followed by delimiter then this is error position on that line